# How to change BOTH seaborn heatmap and colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, heatmap, seaborn

I want to change a seaborn heatmap interactively. However, running `sns.heatmap` twice makes a colorbar multiply ([Fig. 1: Before clicking "Reset"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW1t2.png), [Fig. 2: After clicking "Reset"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTyzl.png)
)

I tried to set `cbar=0` to heatmap in `reset` callback, the text of the colorbar does NOT change, although the scale of the latter matrix is 1000 times large.

Do you know the way to change BOTH a heatmap and a colorbar?
Note that the heatmaps have differenet matrix sizes and different color palettes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = sns.plt.subplots()

sns.heatmap(np.random.rand(10, 12), ax=ax)

resetax = sns.plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')
def reset(event):
    sns.heatmap(np.random.rand(8, 8)*1000, ax=ax, cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True))
button.on_clicked(reset)

sns.plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you want to specify the colorbar axes for the heatmap plot.

Answer (score 1):

If you clear the plot using `plt.clf` in `reset()`, it clears the plot and draws only the new one, see below. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018681/stop-seaborn-plotting-multiple-figures-on-top-of-one-another).

```
def reset(event):
   plt.clf()
   sns.heatmap(np.random.rand(8, 8)*1000, ax=ax, cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True))
```