# Seaborn heatmap overlaps with previous data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas df which I wanted to color code so I used seaborn heatmap to get it done. Works fine for most of the part. But when I create multiple plots, it overlaps with earlier ones.

[image: SNS PLOT]

```
p = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, linewidths=0.3, cmap='RdYlGn').set_title(title)
pl = p.get_figure()
pl.tight_layout()
pl.set_size_inches(dim)
pl.savefig(img_name)
```

This happens when I run this code on multiple dfs or run it with the same df multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clean the plot before every new plotting process..
Check the following answers:

[[Stop seaborn plotting multiple figures on top of one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018681/stop-seaborn-plotting-multiple-figures-on-top-of-one-another])

[When to use cla(), clf() or close() for clearing a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib)